# git: how do "fix" a git branch after a soft reset

Tags: bash, git, merge, console

I always like to review changes on a branch inside my Visual Code Editor. Therefore, I am doing a soft-reset within my terminal:

```sh
kk@macbookpro [10457-fix-encryption]$ git rebase origin/master
kk@macbookpro [10457-fix-encryption]$ git reset --soft origin/master
```

This is really helpful, as I can see the changes which differ from the master directly in the Editor.

Now the problem is, how do I undo the soft-reset? What I was doing so far is, before merging the branch, I have to remove the local branch, and check out the remote branch again:

```sh
kk@macbookpro [10457-fix-encryption]$ git checkout master
kk@macbookpro [master]$ git branch -D 10457-fix-encryption
kk@macbookpro [master]$ git checkout 10457-fix-encryption
kk@macbookpro [10457-fix-encryption]$ git rebase origin/master
kk@macbookpro [10457-fix-encryption]$ git log
// check if everything is ok 
kk@macbookpro [10457-fix-encryption]$ git checkout master
kk@macbookpro [master]$ git merge --no-ff 10457-fix-encryption
```

But as you can see, this is very complicated. And I am sure, this is not the "git way". How to achieve this with less git commands?

**Please help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix an erroneous or unwanted soft reset, simply use another soft reset.  The trick here is finding the right *hash ID*.  Here, reflogs will help: the reflog for the branch that was soft-reset will have in it the hash ID that you would like to use to restore it.  In this particular case, you could also use `ORIG_HEAD`, so that after your:

```
git reset --soft origin/master
```

you could:

```
git reset --soft ORIG_HEAD
```

and be back where you were.

I suspect there's no reason to do that soft-reset in the first place.  There might be, depending on just how anti-clever this "Visual Code Editor" thing may be.  But it seems unlikely.

The thing to keep in mind here is that *branch names* are just mostly just fancy—or convenient—ways of specifying *one particular commit*.  There are plenty of other ways to specify some particular commit.  Let's take a look at your terminal commands here:

> ```
> kk@macbookpro [10457-fix-encryption]$ git rebase origin/master
> ```

This takes some set of commits and *copies* them to new and improved commits.  It then takes the current branch *name*—in this case, `10457-fix-encryption`—and makes it point to the last such copied commit.

The tricky part here is determining exactly which commits will get copied.  The commits that are copied are a subset of those listed by:

```
git log origin/master..HEAD
```

*before* you run the `git rebase` command.  That is, Git will find those commits that are *reachable from* `HEAD`, but not *reachable from* `origin/master`.

The "subset of" above covers a bunch of special cases, where `git rebase` discards commits that do not need to be copied, or shouldn't be copied, for some particular reason.  If we ignore these special cases—which we probably should here—we can draw a typical rebase situation like this:

```
          L   <-- origin/master
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- 10457-fix-encryption (HEAD), origin/10457-fix-encryption
```

Here, each commit hash ID has been replaced with an uppercase letter.  Commits in Git form backwards-looking chains: commit `H`, being the last commit on `master`, points backwards to an earlier commit `G`, which points backwards further, and so on.  Meanwhile commit `K` is the last commit on `10457-fix-encryption`: it points backwards to commit `J`, which points to commit `I`, which points to commit `H`.  You've already run a `git push origin` so that commits `I-J-K` are in another Git repository.  They're mostly ready to be incorporated as is right now, except for one problem: someone else has updated `master` over on `origin` by adding a new commit (or perhaps several, but we'll just draw the one here).  So commit `L` is the tip of *their* branch.

The rebase operation will list out commit hash IDs for commits `I`, `J`, and `K`, as those are the commits that are on `10457-fix-encryption` (which consists of all commits on `master` *plus* `I-J-K`), *minus* all commits on `origin/master` (which consists of commits up through `H` *plus* commit `L`).  The set-subtraction operation here leaves exactly those three commits that are *only* on `10457-fix-encryption`.  Other set-subtraction operations would work too, but this one is fine.

Next, the rebase operation will pick commit `L` as the place the copies should go.  That's because `origin/master` picks commit `L`.  Git will use its so-called detached HEAD mode to check out commit `L`:

```
          L   <-- HEAD, origin/master
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- 10457-fix-encryption, origin/10457-fix-encryption
```

The rebase operation will now proceed to copy, as if by using `git cherry-pick`, each of the commits it listed out earlier.  If and when each copy succeeds, this makes a new commit that applies the same *change* as the original commit.  We can draw these copies like this:

```
            I'-J'-K'  <-- HEAD
           /
          L   <-- origin/master
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- 10457-fix-encryption, origin/10457-fix-encryption
```

Note that at the end of this particular stage of the rebase, `HEAD` now selects copy `K'`, which corresponds to commit `K`.  The rebase code now finishes the rebase by plucking the *name* `10457-fix-encryption` away from commit `K` and making it point instead to commit `K'`:

```
            I'-J'-K'  <-- 10457-fix-encryption (HEAD)
           /
          L   <-- origin/master
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- origin/10457-fix-encryption
```

> ```
> kk@macbookpro [10457-fix-encryption]$ git reset --soft origin/master
> ```

What this does is to move the *current branch name*, without changing what's in Git's *index*, and without changing what's in your *working tree*.  So now the picture of the *commit graph* looks like this:

```
            I'-J'-K'  ???
           /
          L   <-- 10457-fix-encryption (HEAD), origin/master
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- origin/10457-fix-encryption
```

Note that there's no *branch name* for commit `K'` any more.  There are several ways to find it: `ORIG_HEAD`, `10457-fix-encryption@{1}`, and `HEAD@{1}` will all produce the hash ID of commit `K'`:

```
git rev-parse ORIG_HEAD
```

for instance will print out the desired hash ID.

(Hash IDs have the advantage that they never change.  They have the disadvantage of being very long and hard to type and impossible to remember, which is most of why we mostly use names instead of hash IDs.  Names have the further advantage that we can—as `git rebase` or `git reset` do—*move* them to make them select some other commit.  But this of course is also a disadvantage of names: when we move them, we forget what hash ID they *used* to specify.  That's what reflogs are for, but the entries in reflogs all look alike—except for the hash IDs of course—and can be tricky to use.)

Apparently, by having the current branch name identify commit `L` while Git's index and your working tree have, as their contents, the contents of files as they appear in commit `K'`, your editor lets you see these as changes.  But `git diff` will let you see these as changes, without all the mucking about with `git reset`.  Just run:

```
git diff origin/master HEAD
```

to compare those two commits.  (Personally, I like to look at `git log -p` output, or `git format-patch` output, so that I can see *each commit* as a diff against its predecessor.)  Or find some way to make your editor look at some *specific* commit as compared to the current files, rather than using the *current branch name*.  (But maybe there's no way to do that, depending on your editor.)

So, if you really *do* need to do this, you can do it *without* moving the name `10457-fix-encryption` at all.  Just make some other temporary name:

```
git checkout -b tmp
```

so that you have:

```
            I'-J'-K'  <-- 10457-fix-encryption, tmp (HEAD)
           /
          L   <-- origin/master
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- origin/10457-fix-encryption
```

You can now `git reset --soft origin/master` to get:

```
            I'-J'-K'  <-- 10457-fix-encryption
           /
          L   <-- origin/master, tmp (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- origin/10457-fix-encryption
```

When you're done comparing, do another reset (soft, hard, or mixed: it doesn't matter here as what's in the commit you're resetting *to* is what's in Git's index and your work-tree) to the updated branch, after which Git will let you delete `tmp`, then check out `master`:

```
git reset 10457-fix-encryption
git checkout 10457-fix-encryption
git branch -d tmp
git checkout master
```

Or once you're a bit more confident with this workflow, you can:

```
git reset --hard && git checkout master && git branch -D tmp
```

which shuts off various safety checks but gets you down to three commands.

Comment: Torek, thank you for taking your time to answer!

Comment: Thanks for the helpful and nice information :D